# Tags runloop, run-loop, mainrunloop

Tags: discussion, status-declined, retag-request

[runloop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/runloop), [run-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/run-loop), and [mainrunloop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mainrunloop) appear to be exactly the same thing.

Surely the latter two should be eliminated.

Answer (score 2):

- [runloop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/runloop) appears to be language-agnostic.
- [run-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/run-loop) is already a synonym of [runloop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/runloop).
- The two questions with [mainrunloop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mainrunloop) refer to [a method in Apple's Foundation framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsrunloop).